# Caffe and Tensorflow network not giving same accuracy.

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe

I'm training the same network with the same input on both tensor flow and Caffe.
But I get very varied results.
I subtract the same mean and the initialize weights with a similar range of values.
Used the same LR as well.

But there is a huge difference in the accuracy.

Has anyone also had similar issues? And if so how did u overcome them?

This is my [model prototxt](http://pastebin.com/B4GiMjZs), [solver prototxt](http://pastebin.com/H16hNQxH), [tensorflow model](http://pastebin.com/Hs9HUSgF).

**log2_noinitilization is the caffe network**

[image: log2_noinitilization is the caffe network]

[image: log2_noinitilization is the caffe network]

The tensorflow model doesn't even reach an accuracy of 5%.
I have made a lot of runs with diff batch sizes, LR etc.
None of them worked

Comment: You should post this perhaps to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow so the google devs can give it a deeper look. I doubt someone here will be able to find the mistake, or perhaps even bug within the tensorflow framework.

Comment: Sure that make sense but I'm not sure It's a tensorflow bug and thats y I'm hesitant to open a github issue.. But Maybe if a few ppl had a similar problem I could open one..

Comment: Ideally, you should be comparing training (as opposed to testing) accuracies/losses. If I understand correctly, the Caffe pipeline is worse, right? Also, what's the scale of the Y axis in the accuracy plot? Testing seems to saturate at around 0.5, which could either be 0.5% or 50%, where is this 5% number coming from? In any case, Caffe and Tensorflow handle padding, image scaling differently. You should look into this.

Comment: Why are you expecting them to be closer?  What is the derivation of the figures you're plotting?  Remember that these are two different engines, handling transitions in different ways.  They have disparate efficiencies and trade-offs.

Comment: Most likely explanation is that you are using slightly different networks. A similar issue was faced when trying to make TensorFlow work at same accuracy as DistBelief on ImageNet on similar-looking network. There's no easy solution besides checking numerical results at each step and seeing where they differ to find the offending parts, and replacing them to match the numerics of the other

Comment: PS, this is not ideal subject for github issue for because it takes a lot of work to reproduce and it's not clear that it's a bug -- perhaps Caffe is the one that has a bug and this bug acts like regularizer, think dropout

Comment: consider initializing your biases to 0 or at least a constant. For the comparison I think removing as much unnecessary randomness as possible will be helpful.

Comment: I will try to fix the issues mentioned here and edit the post with new results.
@YaroslavBulatov I went through the tensorflow network and found one difference in comparison with the caffe one. @ user728291 will set the biases to constant 0 and edit.